# WiFi high latency

Tags: networking, router, wireless-networking

I got some problems with my WiFi setup.

In my setup I use a Macbook Pro and a TP-Link WR1043ND v1 (OpenWRT).
WiFi Channel is set to 6 (already tried other channels and 20/40Mhz width)

If I ping my macbook or my router from my macbook, the ping is really high.

```
64 bytes from 192.168.1.103: seq=18 ttl=64 time=7.691 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.103: seq=19 ttl=64 time=142.177 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.103: seq=20 ttl=64 time=47.343 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.103: seq=21 ttl=64 time=16.513 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.103: seq=22 ttl=64 time=2.803 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.103: seq=23 ttl=64 time=5.725 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.103: seq=24 ttl=64 time=7.585 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.103: seq=25 ttl=64 time=25.981 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.103: seq=26 ttl=64 time=2.464 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.103: seq=27 ttl=64 time=6.762 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.103: seq=28 ttl=64 time=8.677 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.103: seq=29 ttl=64 time=16.521 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.103: seq=30 ttl=64 time=1.204 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.103: seq=31 ttl=64 time=1.849 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.103: seq=32 ttl=64 time=134.936 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.103: seq=33 ttl=64 time=51.255 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.103: seq=34 ttl=64 time=17.032 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.103: seq=35 ttl=64 time=17.399 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.103: seq=36 ttl=64 time=8.177 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.103: seq=37 ttl=64 time=5.048 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.103: seq=38 ttl=64 time=2.198 ms
```

I already tried another router (Linksys E2000) but its exactly the same.

Comment: Ping is a tool to test for network connectivity, and you shouldn't put too much stock in the reported latency since it doesn't reflect real TCP or UDP performance. Another problem is that this is Wi-Fi, and you are at the mercy of whatever wireless interference you may have, including from other devices on your wireless network since it is a half-duplex medium.

Comment: Such spikes might be caused because of using a rather busy wifi channel. Try to scan your wifi channels with inSSider to find the freest channel and set up your wifi router to use it. This might significantly increase your connectivity.

Answer (score 5):

Your latency is acceptable for Wi-fi networks. My usual latency in 5GHz network is around 15 with 200ms spikes. It is also a good idea to move wireless router across your location in order to identify the best spot for optimal signal coverage.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal for WiFi, but indeed *not* acceptable behavior. If you want to get your hands dirty, check out the make-wifi-fast project from bufferbloat.net. Your access point uses the ath9k wifi chipset, which tends to get improvements first.

Some background on their progress can be found at: http://blog.cerowrt.org/

They've made a network measurement tool called "[flent](http://flent.org/)". Another way to watch the latency is: [Google Fiber's 'blip' tool](http://gfblip.appspot.com)

Maybe something simple you can try right away is build OpenWRT trunk with these [Minstrel-blues](https://github.com/thuehn/Minstrel-Blues) patches. It improves Linux's data rate selection by keeping better statistics on rate effectiveness instead of dropping lower and lower. This *might* improve latency.

Answer (score 0):

As per [@schreda comment](https://superuser.com/revisions/1038780/2), it seems like there is a bug with Chromecast. For some reason Chromecast opens an AP with the same channel as the router it's connected to. This is causing interference.

A factory reset of Chromecast solved this problem. I read that sometimes you have to try it several times to reset Chromecast until the bug doesn't occur anymore.

Comment: If it's just the access-point on the Chrome Cast being a problem, in the setup do not enable "guest mode": http://www.vexperienced.co.uk/2015/07/02/chromecast-causing-wifi-interference-resolved/#comment-131717